# Runtime type introspection with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two types of filter functions: `NodeFilter` and `EdgeFilter`
e.g. `type NodeFilter = (node: Node) => boolean`

I'd like to write a function `Graph::filter(filters: NodeFilter | EdgeFilter): Graph` which applies the filters to nodes and edges of the Graph, to create a new Graph.

So in filter I need to do

```
if (filter is type NodeFilter) nodes = nodes.filter(filter)
else if (filter is type EdgeFilter) edges = edges.filter(filter)
```

I've seen recommendations of adding a "type" property to instances. e.g.

```
function myNodeFilter(node: Node): boolean { // do the filtering and return boolean }
myNodeFilter.type = "NodeFilter";
```

Is there a better way? Maybe defining a callable class instance?

Comment: Does the caller not know which function it is passing? If so, could it?

Comment: Type information is striped during the build process. You can only determine the type of values with the tools that *JavaScript* gives you, and since JS is dynamically typed you cannot determine what "type" of argument a function expects. I.e. you have to find another: Add a flag (as suggested with `type`) or accept multiple arguments (node and edge filters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use descriminated unions for this with a sprinkle of call signature.

```js
/**
* Kindly ignore the naming,
* it was conflicting with the DOM Node and NodeFilter function (since I tested this in typescript playground)
**/
type NodeF = {};
type Edge = {}
type NodeFilterr = {
    (node: NodeF): boolean,
    type: "NodeFilter"
}

type EdgeFilter = {
    (edge: Edge): boolean,
    type: "EdgeFilter"
}

function f(filter: NodeFilterr | EdgeFilter ) {
    if ( filter.type === "NodeFilter" ) {
        // do stuff
    }
    if ( filter.type === "EdgeFilter" ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```